# Join to the same room in different namespace

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using `socket.io v 2.0.4` and 
I have 3 name-spaces which there is no relation between them. But sometimes i need to join sockets in different names-paces, to the same room. Is it possible?

I saw lots of solutions and posts but they didn't helped me in socket.io v 2.0 .

Using `socket.io-redis`:

```
const express = require('express') ;
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const Redis = require('ioredis');
const redis = new Redis({host: 'localhost',port: 6379});

const redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');

io.adapter(redisAdapter(
  {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379,
    requestsTimeout: 5000
  }
));

const t = io.of('/t') ;
const d = io.of('/d') ;

const dNamespace= (socket) => {
   socket.on('t.join',(tRoom)=>{
      t.adapter.remoteJoin(socket.id, tRoom, (err) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err) ;
      })
   })
};

d.on('connection',dNamespace) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use socket.io-redis for remote join

```
io.of('/namespace').adapter.remoteJoin('<my-id>', 'room1', (err) => {
  if (err) { /* unknown id */ }
  // success
});
```

Comment: It uses ```publish``` command on redis and:
```Error: timeout reached while waiting for remoteJoin response
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/SocketApp/node_modules/socket.io-redis/index.js:591:46)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:466:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:267:5)```

Comment: this error comes when socketId is not live.
i was getting same error when i was using some socketId stored in DB,took me while to figure it out.

Comment: Actually socket is alive and i can see socket.id !

Comment: hmm,
could you try io.of('/') instead of giving any namespace?

Comment: same error with `io.of('/').adapter.remoteJoin(socket.id, tRoom,(err)=>{})`

Comment: it works like this: `io.of('/').adapter.remoteJoin(socket.client.id, tRoom,(err)=>{})` but it seems needs the clients connected to main name-space.